# how to search encrypted emails efiiciently

Tags: search-engine

implement like search engine for encrypted emails..But the encrypted emails can be decrypted when performing searching ...likewise whenever search button is clicked it decrypts all emails one by one and copies to text file and perform efficient search technique (by lucene) to get quick results.

Comment: Please be clear in your question...what encryption algorithm? are you talking of decryption on the fly?

Comment: Would be great to have a nice tool for this. I am missing for example in thunderbird such a feature for a long time now...

Comment: Perhaps this answer may be interesting for you: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46844/5289